# React.js + Vite based project, after Build showing: "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON"

Tags: reactjs, vite, vercel

First thank you very much for looking at my question ˙ᵕ˙
This is my first time to post, and hope all the contents are clear and look structured.

I am using **React.js** and **vite** to build an website and hosting using **Vercel**. ([chwa-web.vercel.app](https://chwa-web.vercel.app))

It was working fine on my localhost to fetch some data from other site,
but when hosting on Vercel, it is not working anymore and showing the error message:
VM1046:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
(I understood that I don't get a right json format data. And I should make a right path, but since it was working fine on localhost, not sure if I have a wrong path?)

It would be really appreciated to get some help to fix this problem.

I share my code as below and also photos just in case if there is any information for this problem

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Reveal from './utils/Reveal';
import FavoriteOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FavoriteOutlined';


const Review = () => {

    const [articles, setArticles] = useState([])

    const fetchData = () => {
        const apiUrl = '/v1/search/blog?query=' + encodeURI('주화시장 검보 맛집') + '&display=8';

        return fetch(apiUrl, {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type':'application/json',
                        'X-Naver-Client-Id': import.meta.env.VITE_API_BLOG_KEY_ID,
                        'X-Naver-Client-Secret': import.meta.env.VITE_API_BLOG_KEY_SECRET
                    }
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                setArticles(data.items);})
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData()
    },[])

    return (. ... more code..

}

export default Review
```

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  assetsInclude: ['**/*.glb'],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/v1': {
        target: 'https://openapi.naver.com',
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),
        secure: false,
        ws: true,
      }
    }
  },
})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRuYo.png)

localhost working fine, and on vercel not showing:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zF6lY.png)

I can see that its response html of my html! which I could not quite understand:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ml5wD.png)

- I added *https://chwa-web.vercel.app* on the API provider
- I tried to host using other hosting service such as Namecheap, and there was also not working.
- I have tried to change `rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ''),` -> `rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/v1/, ''),`

Most of result of researches were changing the path or it is not working on localhost.
It would be really appreciated to get some help..

Thanks and wish you all a nice day.

Comment: Sounds like when you are doing `.then((response) => response.json())`, `response` is actually HTML and not JSON. I would use your browser devtools to compare the network requests and responses when you're running on localhost and it's working, vs when you're running on the server and it's not working. Something about the network requests/responses is behaving differently

Comment: @AlexvonBrandenfels thanks for the commenting! I found out the solution, its working on vercel also ˙ᵕ˙

Answer (score 0):

I found out that setting up **proxy in `vite.config.js` is only working for the dev environment.**
You can set up the proxy on **`vercel.json` file to make that work on vercel.**

In my case, I made the `vercel.json` file as following since before `/v1/` should have the API provider origin address

```
{
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/v1/:path*",
      "destination": "https://openapi.naver.com/v1/:path*"
    }
  ]
}
```

for more information about this, you can check here: https://vercel.com/docs/edge-network/rewrites

hope this post is helpful anyone who had same problem ..

Then happy coding ˙ᵕ˙